# Cauchy-Euler equation change of variables

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Suppose we have the differential equation $ax^2y''+bxy'+cy = 0;$ one method of solving it according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) involves making the variable substitution $t=\ln(x)$ and $y(x)=f(\ln(x))=f(t).$ However, I am struggling to understand how they are able to compute the first and second derivatives of $y(x)$ with regard to this substitution.

Comment: They use the chain rule here, for instance for the first derivative:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{1}{x}$$
Can you do the second derivative?

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$y(x)=f(\ln(x))\implies y'(x)=\frac1xf'(t)\implies y''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}f'(t)+\frac1{x^2}f''(t)$$

and therefore

$$ax^2y''+bxy'+cy = 0 \implies -af'(t)+af''(t)+bf'(t)+cf(t)=0$$

that is

$$af''(t)+(b-a)f'(t)+cf(t)=0$$

Answer (score 1):

The other answer covers it, but I guess it is worth remarking that another (easier?) way to solve the Cauchy-Euler equation is to try the solution $y(x)=x^m$, then we obtain a characteristic equation, $am(m-1)+bm+c = 0$, from which we can produce two linearly independent solutions to the differential equation, depending on the roots of the characteristic equation, and thus, the general solution.